# Is this proof for $\sum^n_{i=1} i= \frac{n^2+n}{2}$ correct?

Tags: proof-verification

Is this proof correct, as I feel unsure about whether or not I did that correct because the book did it differently, I wouldn't know however why my proof should be wrong.

Could you help me out?

The following statement is to be proven by induction.
$$\sum^n_{i=1} = \frac{n^2+n}{2}$$
Base case $n=1$
$$1 = \frac{1+1}{2} \checkmark $$ 
Induction Step $n\rightarrow n+1$
$$\sum^{n+1}_{i=1}=\sum^n_{i=1}+(n+1)\\
 \iff \frac{n^2+n}{2}+(n+1) \\
 \iff \frac{n^2+n}{2}+\frac{2(n+1)}{2} \\
 \iff \frac{n^2+n+2n+2}{2}\\
 \iff \frac{n^2+3n+2}{2} \\
 \iff \frac{(n+1)^2+(n+1)}{2} $$

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Comment: Let try to improve you question using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @thebilly have you seen Gauss' solution to this problem, it is quite elegant.

Comment: @gimusi Yes I could do that, but that is a lot of work... I'd spend more time writing this into mathjax than solving my problems, which i guess is rather bad time management in regards to exams. is it not ok to post quick questions in pictures?

Comment: @thebilly Your question is good, you have shown your work and indeed you have received also a good number of upvotes. Anyway your question should be edited using Mathjax according to the guidelines [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/505767). That's important to create and share a collection of questions and answers which can be used as source and reference also by users in the future.

Comment: @thebilly Moreover it could be also useful for your career improve your skills in mathematical typing.

Comment: @gimusi i see. I'll edit it.

Comment: @thebilly That's nice! Do not hesitate to ask if you need some help. Note that you can past and copy the text you need from any source by copy and paste.

Comment: @gimusi thank you. I'd have one question. Do I use the $ \iff $ as the sign to show following transformations?(I am unsure because it says this is the logically equivalent sign and I guess I want to show algebraic equaivalence...

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is correct indeed, also according to the usual way to write that foundamental identity, that is

$$\sum^n_{i=1} i= \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

at the end we obtain

$$\sum^{n+1}_{i=1} i= \frac{n^2+3n+2}{2}= \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}$$

Refer also to the related

- [Using Direct Proof. $1+2+3+\ldots+n = \frac{n(n + 1)}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/910468/505767)

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Comment: @thebilly You are welcome bye.